# How can I differentiate between $ (jQuery) and $scope from AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

In jQuery, we do DOM Manipulation like,

```
$(this).hide();
```

whereas in AngularJS , we have the scope of the controller using which we can do a lot.

```
$(scope).somevar=somevalue;
```

Can we compare these two different Javascript Objects?

Comment: Ehh... do you ever do `$(scope)` in your controller?

Comment: Question really doesn't make sense. `scope` isn't a css selector or dom element. What real problem are you having?

Comment: One can also have $(selector) in Prototype for example..the '$' or 'dollar' sign is it's not proprietary to any library. You can use it in your code as well as a part of variable name. But In angularJS you would only have $scope.myVar syntax - without brackets

Comment: `$` and `$scope` are two different variables and they aren't related at all.

Answer (score 2):

`$(scope)` is not proper angular syntax AFAIK. The dollar sign `$` in JS is not a special character. it can be part of a variable like a lot of other symbols.

There is no conflict natively between jQuery's `$` and angular's `$scope, $resource, $q` etc. They're different variables, just like `j, jscope, jresource, jq` would be different variables.

As for comparing these values, you're in a severe case of apples to oranges. jQuery-wrapped DOM elements may be comparable to arbitrary values in your scope but you'd have to determine some meaningful way to perform that comparison.